# I am creating a function to create a node directly in C . However, I do not know how to implement the naming part of the node

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I am leaving a question while implementing the linked list in the c language. I am creating a function to create a node directly. However, I do not know how to implement the naming part of the node. This is my code.

```
listnode *create_node(char name,int data,listnode *link){
    listnode *name;
    name = (listnode *)malloc(sizeof(listnode));
    name->data = data;
    name->link = link;
    return(name);
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please show how you are calling this function. Are there any errors or something unexpected?

Comment: What are you trying to name exactly?

Comment: Yes, when I declare the name part 
The compiler outputs the following error

Comment: node_study.c:41:16: error: ‘name’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
     listnode *(name);

                ^~~~

Comment: you have a `char name` in the parameter and also a `listnode *name` in the function local variable. This is the reason for the above compiler error. You need to change one of the above.

Comment: This structure is also used this way
    insert_node(&head_2,NULL,create_node('p4',40,NULL));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need change the `char name` to `char n`. hahahaha

Because you declare the same local variable `listnode *name` as the parameter `char name`

Comment: Then I can not create a node name?

Comment: What I want is to name the node as a parameter  ㅠoㅠ

Comment: @이용현 mmmmmmm....what's your mean of 'name the node as a parameter'? change the `char name` to `char n` does not affect anything except the error. By the way , the parameter `char name` is even not used in the function body. if you are creating a binary tree by node with two children, then delete the `char name`....(￣▽￣)~*

Comment: I just want to name this part...

listnode *name;

Comment: oh~ then you just change the name of `char name`. ￣ω￣=